# Python: using os.execlp() with the path being a variable

Tags: python, batch-file, code-translation

I am converting a program from Batch to Python. Here is how I think I could do translate the Batch

> %VBM% sharedfolder add %VMNAME% --name "LogDir" --hostpath %LogDir%

into:

```
os.execlp(VBM, 'sharedfolder', 'add', VMNAME, '--name', "LogDir",'--hostpath', LogDir)
```

My questions:

1. Considering VBM, VMNAME, and LogDir are variables that are declared
   beforehand within my script, is my translation correct?
2. Is it ok that I represent the Path string with a variable, e.g. VBM
3. What could be a better way of doing any of the above?

Comment: This might work better: `os.execlp(VBM, 'sharedfolder', 'add', VMNAME, '--name', '"LogDir"', '--hostpath', LogDir)` assuming `VBM`,  `VMNAME`, and `LogDir` values are all strings.

Comment: If you want your Python script to continue execution, you should use the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: Hi, @Guillaume. Sorry, but I do not understand your comment/edit.

Comment: Hi @martineau, is using os.execlp like I did or like Guillaume suggested not a a subprocess?

Comment: @AlainRafiki I did not commented on your post...

Comment: @Guillaume Oh, I just noticed that both are signed by martineau. I'm sorry.

Comment: `execlp` executes a new program, replacing the current process - i.e. it doesn't return. `subprocess.call()` spawns a subprocess and waits for it to complete. It uses the `subprocess.Popen` class for the underlying process creation.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up just using subprocess.call()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go ahead and use subprocess.call() and it works.